# jQuery is not working in any version of ie?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery

I'm a beginning programmer on a mac (so I don't have ie) and built a relatively simple ajax jquery application where based on what `$msg` is stored in the database, it shows form elements (could be a button, a select/dropdown, or just text and a link) that upon being clicked, go back to the database and change the `$msg`.

My code works great in Chrome and Firefox, but form elements (at the 5 second lag) revert to where they were when you loaded the page when I tested in all versions of IE. After getting frustrated, I looked up SO answers and read about doctypes sometimes being problematic, so I changed the doctype to the html5 doctype and nothing changed.

Heres my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  



$('.checkIn').click(function() {
    var $e = $(this);
    var data = $e.data("param").split('_')[1] ;
    // gets the id  of button  (1 for the first button)
    // You can map this to the corresponding button in database...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkin.php",
        // Data used to set the values in Database
        data: { "checkIn" : $(this).val(), "buttonId" : data},
        success: function() {
            // Hide the current Button clicked
            $e.hide();
            var $container = $e.closest("div.jcontainer");
            // Get the immediate form for the button
            // find the select inside it and show...

            $container.find('.locationSelect').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
$('.reset').click(function() {
    var $e = $(this);
    var data = $e.data("param").split('_')[1] ;
    // gets the id  of button  (1 for the first button)
    // You can map this to the corresponding button in database...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reset.php",
        // Data used to set the values in Database
        data: { "reset" : $(this).val(), "buttonId" : data},
        success: function() {
            // Hide the current Button clicked
            $e.fadeOut();

            var $container = $e.closest("div.jcontainer");
            // Get the immediate form for the button
            // find the select inside it and show...
            $container.find('.finished').fadeOut();
            $container.find('.checkIn').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
$('.locationSelect').change(function(e) {
  if($(this).children(":selected").val() === "CheckOut") {
    $e = $(this);
    var data = $e.data("param").split('_')[1] ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkout.php",
        // Data used to set the values in Database
        data: { "checkOut" : $(this).val(), "buttonId" : data},
        success: function() {
            // Hide the current Button clicked
            $e.fadeOut();
            var $container = $e.closest("div.jcontainer");
            // Get the immediate form for the button
            // find the select inside it and show...
            $container.find('reset').fadeIn();
            $container.find('.finished').fadeIn();

        }
    });
  }
  else{
    $e = $(this);
    var data = $e.data("param").split('_')[1] ;
    // gets the id  of select (1 for the first select)
    // You can map this to the corresponding select in database...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "changeloc.php",
        data: { "locationSelect" : $(this).val(), "selectid" : data},
        success: function() {
            // Do something here
        }
    });
  }
});
setInterval(function(){

    $('.jcontainer').each(function() {
        var $e = $(this);
        var dataid = $e.data("param").split('_')[1] ;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'heartbeat.php',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: true,
            data: { "dataid": dataid },
            success: function(data){


                var msg = $.parseJSON(data);

                if (msg == ""){ //after reset or after new patient that is untouched is added, show checkin
                    $e.find('.checkIn').show();
                    $e.find('.locationSelect').hide();
                    $e.find('.finished').hide();
                    $e.find('.reset').hide();
                }
                if ((msg < 999) && (msg > 0)){ // after hitting "Check In", Checkin button is hidden, and locationSelect is shown
                    $e.find('.checkIn').hide();
                    $e.find('.locationSelect').show();
                    $e.find('.finished').hide();
                    $e.find('.reset').hide();
                    $e.find('.locationSelect').val(msg);
                }
                if (msg == 1000){ //after hitting "Checkout", Option to reset is shown and "Finished!"
                    $e.find('.checkIn').hide();
                    $e.find('.locationSelect').hide();
                    $e.find('.finished').show();
                    $e.find('.reset').show();
                }


            }
       });


    });
  },5000);
});
```

I tried to comment as much of my code as I could, but basically what the first part does is just upload the `$msg` to my php page for each type of interaction with form elements (button being clicked, select option being hit, link being clicked). Then the second part is a refresh every 5 seconds to make sure the form element being currently shown on Computer 1 is shown (with a 5 sec lag) on Computer 2.

Thanks for any and all help, and if you need more details/info, just ask! Thanks!

Comment: Code looks fine, nothing here indicates that there should be a problem with Internet Explorer. You're going to have to be more specific than 'gets all whacky'. We'll need to see any errors being produced in the console, if there are none, you'll need to be more descriptive.

Comment: How are you including jQuery on the page? is it possible IE is either not loading the resource or there is a script error in the page that's causing all other scripts to fail (but chrome/ff suppress it)? -- Follow-Up: I've found IE can occasionally fail on object declarations (`{foo:'bar'}`) and have since used quotes for the property names (`{'foo':'bar'}`).

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific about the failure than just saying that things "get all wacky".

Comment: The error is that when in Chrome (or FF) I can click for example the last option in the select "Check Out", which is supposed to show .finished and .reset (which it does in FF and Chrome), but in IE instead redirects to the .locationSelect again, skipping the .finished and .reset?

Comment: @BradChristie, I checked and IE is loading the JQuery, and I commented all of the other scripts out, and its still not working? Thanks for the tip about object declarations, I'll check it out

Comment: @Jake: Nothing in the console or script errors popping up?

Comment: @BradChristie, sorry I'm actually trying to read how to use the console right now, but I checked Chrome Developer Tools and no errors came up so far.

Comment: Put an `alert` inside of `document.ready` and see if that simply comes up or not

Comment: @Jake As you're learning and most developers know--there's noting traditional about IE, unfortunately. so just because every other browser on the planet works doesn't mean IE will. Assuming you're using a recent version of IE, press `F12` on the page, go to the script tab, click _Start Debugging_ then refresh the page. See if anything pops up.

Comment: @BradChristie I can't imagine IE breaking on unquoted keys in an object literal. However, it will break in some IE when you put a comment after the last key/value pair, if that's what you meant

Comment: @Ian: It was more a "for instance" than the sole purpose. FWIW, it was while using keywords as object properties that IE choked (at least the version i worked on at the time). But I'm imagining it's something that gives purpose to libraries like the [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).

Comment: @BradChristie, Thanks for the help on that. I used the Start Debugging and nothing came up. What does this mean?

Comment: Chances are there isn't a error. However, you can set breakpoints by clicking to the far left of the code and then run the page again and step through. See if your script is being executed and runs as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what problem it is you're experiencing so I'm sorry if this is way off, but it may be that IE is caching your Ajax requests. You can try inserting this before your functions:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false
});
```

Note: If this works, don't leave the final code like this. Disabling the Ajax caching for all browsers is not a good idea, but sometimes it needs to be done for older versions of IE. I would recommend utilising IE conditional comments in your HTML, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie10 ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html class='no-js'>
  <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then you can detect IE and the `$.ajaxSetup` could look like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: !$('html').hasClass('lt-ie9'); //false if lower than IE9
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Also in my code, I actually called `cache: true` for my 5 sec refresh. thanks a load!